# C# Remove duplicates from list without LINQ and withoiut HashSet (framework less than .Net 3.5)

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I've got applicatipon based on c# where i can do some custom scripts and i need to REMOVE DUPLICATES from one list

**but**

***I can't use LINQ*** (and it's Distinct() method - cause Net Framework of app is < 3.5) cause application ***doesn't recognize it and also it doesn't recognize HashSet method*** so am a bit confused with it, any ideas ?

this is list of strings, for example:

`List<string> withDuplicates= new List<string>(new string[] { "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"});`

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary`, but set the value to `null`

Comment: Don't forget, [the source code of a HashSet](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs) is also available if you want to copy it and roll it into your project, but like the comment in that source code says, a hashset is practically just a dictionary with no values support. If you don't have a Dictionary, .net's had a [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-6.0) from birth, I think..